# Reduce file size of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

So i'm tried to reduce video filesize by scale down video `-vf 640:-2`, but nothing changes. Scale down or up doesnt affect video filesize

I've read ffmpeg wiki about Scaling but it dont have any information about scale and filesize.

When i'm scale down images, filesize have big drop but for video, nothing changes

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information. You need to show all the information about your video both before and after your attempt to reduce its size. Try using `ffprobe` on both.

Comment: i found other answer on website, he's said that resolution and codec are two different things, to reduce file size you must use better codec, in this case i'm using libx265

Answer (score 2):

You can use -crf option to reduce final video size.

The range of the CRF scale is 0–51, where 0 is lossless (for 8 bit only, for 10 bit use -qp 0), 23 is the default, and 51 is worst quality possible.

```
-crf 23 (for default)
```

You have to use H.264 encoder. this will help almost all type of video. works batter in mp4 videos.

Comment: yes, -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -x265-params profile=main10 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p10le
with this, quality is better and file size is lower but encode time is longer, -vf scale is just for visual, not for size/quality

Comment: You can use '-preset ultrafast' for decrease conversion time. use that before your add your output path.

Comment: ok thank you, i will try that, hope quality is same and encode time is reduce

Comment: look like ultrafast = higher size, not reduce size at all, should fast or slow

Comment: -crf use for reduce the size of video and -preset is use for decrease conversion time. I personally used that.

Comment: Can you do sound and video separately? Like I want perfect sound but the video can be trash. It's for creating subtitles. Then I can add the subtitles to the high-quality video afterwards.